# How to Extract Meta Title using R?

Tags: r, metadata

I want to use R to extract ALL META Tiles

Here're the URL:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8031422/

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8962124/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975976/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

So, the outcome should be: The Last Sharknado: It's About Time, Emily in Paris and Lalaland

Can you please teach me how to do?

And, I want to create a table with 2 columns, 1 column for URL and 1 column for Title

I'm just a newbie, I really dont know about R. Please teach me!
Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO! Universities charge top dollar for such questions. Could you include some tools/packages/resources you have looked at, and code you have written (but didn't work?). For your needs, I suggest `rvest` ([docs](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/articles/rvest.html)) and ([more docs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rvest)) for secondary discovery. An example is `library(rvest); read_html(url) |> html_element("h1") |> html_text()`.

Comment: Thank you for that! Here's my code. I can only do 1

Comment: library(rvest)
    ht <- read_html('https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aimdb.com+%22The+Last+Sharknado%3A+It%27s+About+Time%22&num=100')
    links <- ht %>% html_nodes(xpath='//a') %>% html_attr('href')
    gsub('/url\\?q=','',sapply(strsplit(links[as.vector(grep('url',links))],split='&'),'[',1))

Comment: Here's the URL to scrap 100 URL for site:imdb.com "The Last Sharknado: It's About Time" https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aimdb.com+%22The+Last+Sharknado%3A+It%27s+About+Time%22&num=100

Comment: I want to extract meta title, meta description and H1 from these 100 urls. Can you please show me how to do it. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just another question. When I extract URL, I found some URLs are not working. but I do see these URLs on Google and the URL link is working. Just wonder why R cannot scarp the URL. EG: this is the link & it's working https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title=The%20Last%20Sharknado%3A%20It%27s%20About%20Time&sort=runtime,asc  Here's the link scrap from R & it's not working  "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/%3Ftitle%3DThe%2520Last%2520Sharknado%253A%2520It%2527s%2520About%2520Time%26sort%3Druntime,asc"                                                                                    
.